# 3d print an area from Google Earth

Tags: export, google-earth, 3d-model

Is it possible to extract all 3d data (terrain + objects: buildings, vegetation, landmarks, etc.) from Google Earth in an easy way and 3d print it? I found tutorials about extracting the terrain itself, but I would like to print a section of a city which is nicely populated with detailed models.
Since it would still cover a larger area, downloading and printing the buildings separately is not an option.

Comment: 3d printed as in http://terrainator.com/ ?

Comment: yes, but the point is to include the buildings, trees and all 3d content _as well as_ the terrain itself

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has this question, I found a way at least to export an area (up to 800m x 800m per file) of buildings at once from Google Earth (well, from OSM, which is the source of most of the buildings in GE).  I don't know if it takes terrain variations into account (at that resolution, inside a city there probably isn't so much variation anyways):

http://blog.osmbuildings.org/2015/12/3d-print-at-wherecamp-2015_3.html

Comment: Do the buildings in Google Earth really come from OSM?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to see if there's LiDAR data for the area you are looking at.  Go to [NSF OpenTopography](http://opentopo.sdsc.edu/gridsphere/gridsphere?cid=datasets) to see if there is any available for your area.  Then Shapespeare on YouTube has a pretty straightforward tutorial on how to print from LiDAR data [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4-ICkvyJv0).

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's still just the terrain whereas I'd like to have the 3D models of trees, houses etc. which exist in Google Earth